# Adding bootsrap carousel control button automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a jquery function to add bootstrap indicators automatically but I want to add `carousel control` too like sample code which is in below and carousel-control href must be same value with carousel id how can I do that ?

```
 <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myCarousels = $(".carousel");
  myCarousels.each(function(index, element) {
    var myCarousel = $("#" + $(element).attr('id'));
    myCarousel.append("<ol class='carousel-indicators'></ol>");
    var indicators = $("#" + $(element).attr('id') + " .carousel-indicators");
    $("#" + $(element).attr('id') + " .carousel-inner").children(".item").each(function(index) {
      (index === 0) ?
      indicators.append("<li data-target='#" + $(element).attr('id') + "' data-slide-to='" + index + "' class='active'></li>"):
        indicators.append("<li data-target='#" + $(element).attr('id') + "' data-slide-to='" + index + "'></li>");
    });
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
.carousel {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: #faa82b !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" /><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>


  <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://www.jssor.com/img/home/01.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.jssor.com/img/home/02.jpg">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- carousel 1-->


  <div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://www.jssor.com/img/home/03.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.jssor.com/img/home/04.jpg">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- carousel 2-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No magic. Just append left and right controls to main carousel container (I used `$(element).attr('id')` to change href attribute, it's very similar to your indicators, even easier, you don't have to check if the element is first to add `active` class.

```
var myCarousels = $(".carousel");
myCarousels.each(function(index, element) {
  var myCarousel = $("#" + $(element).attr('id'));
  myCarousel.append("<ol class='carousel-indicators'></ol>");
  var indicators = $("#" + $(element).attr('id') + " .carousel-indicators");
  $("#" + $(element).attr('id') + " .carousel-inner").children(".item").each(function(index) {
    (index === 0) ?
    indicators.append("<li data-target='#" + $(element).attr('id') + "' data-slide-to='" + index + "' class='active'></li>"):
      indicators.append("<li data-target='#" + $(element).attr('id') + "' data-slide-to='" + index + "'></li>");
  });
  var controls = '<a class="left carousel-control" href="#' + $(element).attr('id') + '" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#' + $(element).attr('id') + '" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>';
  $(controls).appendTo($(element));
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/WRzgBR)

Comment: it's great but it has added one more than carousel conrol if you inspect element so thanks

Comment: Yeah small bug with parentheses. Edited.